# Can /apps be extracted from a variable with /apps/ow/... in one line?

Tags: bash

The string is: `fs=/apps/ow/abc/xyz/def/`

```
IFS=/ read -r fs fs rest <<< "$fs"
fs="/"$fs
```

I want to extract only first part i.e. output should be `/apps` only - in one liner.

There are various techniques including read and string deletion in bash but I want to make use of single liner built in bash command without any external bash command.

Comment: Generally speaking, quests for a one-liner are a bad idea. You should be trying to build readable, maintainable code, not code that's terse in clever ways.

Comment: @Aaron, that would need to be `<<<"$fs"`, and it trims the leading `/`. It's also extremely inefficient at runtime, since it's spinning up an external tool just to process one line. Native string manipulations, as given in [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100), are generally preferable -- though if the OP *truely* prefers terseness, perhaps they *want* something that's one command but takes 100x longer to run, vs two separate internal commands?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy right, thanks for the info

Comment: You can trivially join those two commands with `&&`, although I would also recommend not reusing `fs` so many times. Something like `IFS=/ read -r _ x _ <<< "$fs" &&
fs="/$x"`.

Answer (score 3):

The single command:

```
[[ $fs =~ ^(/[^/]+)/ ]]
```

...will assign your desired result (`/apps`) to `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`.

Comment: Other way could be: 

x=${fs#?} && fs="/"${x%%/*}

Comment: @AshwaniKumar, I'd prefer `${fs#/}` -- that way we only prune the character we expect to be present. And you don't need to quote the `/`, which is constant -- if you're going to quote anything (which is optional in an assignment), be sure that you're quoting the *expansion*, which is what can (in non-assignment contexts) *need* quoting to suppress string-splitting and globbing behaviors. Thus, `x=${fs#/}; fs=/${x%%/*}`, or `x="${fs#/}"; fs="/${x%%/*}"`

Comment: @AshwaniKumar, ...even those versions I don't like that as much as what's given in the answer, though; if your string *doesn't* start with a leading `/` they'll silently add one instead of indicating an error (though at least unlike your version it won't kill the first non-slash character instead).

Comment: Thanks for nice reply. The string does start with a  leading /.

Comment: @AshwaniKumar, yes, you expect it to -- so if it *doesn't*, it's better to detect that as an error (for instance, you could put `|| { echo "fs must start with a /" >&2; exit 1; }` after a `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]` to abort execution when no match is found) than to silently generate invalid or corrupt data. The worst data loss incidents I've seen (caused by bad code rather than operator error) took place when something that was assumed to be impossible... happened. The defense is to *habitually* ensure robust error handling, even against the "impossible".

Comment: @AshwaniKumar, (...and, on that point: To make sure something is habit when it counts, it helps to follow that same practice even when you don't think it does).